# How exacty does the display: flex property work on a container div, and the flex property work on a div child?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to understand exactly how the `display: flex` property works in this layout: http://www.html.it/demo/javascript/55905/demo_index.html

As you can see in this layout there is an external div container having **id="com"** and that have this CSS:

```
.com {
    align-items: stretch;
    display: flex;
    height: 100vh;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

So it have set the **display: flex;** coupled with the **align-items: stretch;** properties. So, reading here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

It seems to me that it is defining a container in which the element are put one next to the other, but I am absolutely not sure if I am missing something.

Then, inside this container that defined the content having `id="com__content"`, this one:

```
<div class="com__content">
```

that have the following CSS settings associated:

```
.com__content {
    background: #404855 none repeat scroll 0 0;
    flex: 8 1 0;
    padding: 10vh 10vw;
    position: relative;
}
```

Also this internal component have something related to the flex behavior.

What exactly does the `flex: 8 1 0;` property on this div mean?

Comment: To start with you seem to be confusing ID and class.  Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.   Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flex: 8 1 0;` 

is shortcut stand for 'flex-grow', 'flex-shrink' and 'flex-basis'
 first flex-grow 8 means: this div totally have 8/ total space

for exmple: 
you have a `div.first flex-grow: 1;`
and another `div.second flex-grow: 2;`
the first div have only 1/3 psace in this line, and left over would be second div's place.
`flex-shrink`
This defines the ability for a flex item to shrink if necessary.
value 1 mean shrink 1 times

last `flex-basis`
defines the default size of an element before the remaining space is distributed.

you can setup as  It can be a length(20% or 100px), it specifies the initial size of the flex item

as your mentions that article [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) had metion

> flex
>   This is the shorthand for flex-grow, flex-shrink and flex-basis combined. The second and third parameters (flex-shrink and flex-basis) are optional. Default is 0 1 auto.